# STM32F4 one GPIO EXTI fires multiple interrupts

Tags: debugging, embedded, interrupt, gpio, stm32f4

An STM32F446 is used to detect multiple push button interrupts.  The GPIO inputs are pulled down externally by 10K resistors. A valid press should be at 3.3V and release at 0V.  The GPIO mode is set to be rising/falling edge trigger detections so that the debouncing algorithm would know the time duration for a valid button press.
When I tested the system, I found one valid button pressing will trigger multiple other interrupts.

I've scoped the false triggered pin, no noise and spikes were found.
I put a breakpoint in the HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback() function to check both button 1 and 5 GPIO Pin handler.  The program will stop at button 1 handler routine each time I pressed button 5, and then the program will stop at button 5 routine for the next round.
The debouncing algorithm works fine to filter out those random unintended interrupts.
I want to know why one button press will trigger other interrupts even through there is no voltage change on the triggered pin.

Inside HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin):

```
if(GPIO_Pin == SM_BTN0_Pin)
{
    btn_debouncing(BTN_0, &swBtn[0]);
    if(steeringModeSwBtnFlag)   tmpSwBtn = swBtn[0];
}
else if(GPIO_Pin == SM_BTN1_Pin)
{
    btn_debouncing(BTN_1, &swBtn[1]);
    if(steeringModeSwBtnFlag)   tmpSwBtn = swBtn[1];
}
else if(GPIO_Pin == SM_BTN5_Pin)
{
    btn_debouncing(BTN_5, &swBtn[5]);
    if(steeringModeSwBtnFlag)   tmpSwBtn = swBtn[5];
}else;
```

Disassembly:

```
08000e9c:   b.n     0x8000ffc <HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback+1008>
206                     btn_debouncing(BTN_1, &swBtn[1]);
08000e9e:   movs    r1, #128        ; 0x80
08000ea0:   ldr     r0, [pc, #88]   ; (0x8000efc <HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback+752>)
08000ea2:   bl      0x8008d08 <HAL_GPIO_ReadPin>
08000ea6:   mov     r3, r0
08000ea8:   ldr     r1, [pc, #92]   ; (0x8000f08 <HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback+764>)
08000eaa:   mov     r0, r3
08000eac:   bl      0x80014f0 <btn_debouncing>
207                     if(steeringModeSwBtnFlag)   tmpSwBtn = swBtn[1];
08000eb0:   ldr     r3, [pc, #68]   ; (0x8000ef8 <HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback+748>)
08000eb2:   ldrb    r3, [r3, #0]
08000eb4:   uxtb    r3, r3
08000eb6:   cmp     r3, #0
08000eb8:   beq.w   0x8001000 <HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback+1012>
08000ebc:   ldr     r2, [pc, #68]   ; (0x8000f04 <HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback+760>)
08000ebe:   ldr     r3, [pc, #64]   ; (0x8000f00 <HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback+756>)
08000ec0:   mov     r4, r2
08000ec2:   adds    r3, #12
08000ec4:   ldmia.w r3, {r0, r1, r2}
08000ec8:   stmia.w r4, {r0, r1, r2}
```

In main.h:

```
...
#define RISING        1u
#define FALLING       0u
...
#define SM_BTN0_Pin   GPIO_PIN_8
#define SM_BTN1_Pin   GPIO_PIN_7
#define SM_BTN5_Pin   GPIO_PIN_5
...
#define BTN_0   HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOE, SM_BTN0_Pin)
#define BTN_1   HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOE, SM_BTN1_Pin)
#define BTN_5   HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOE, SM_BTN5_Pin)
...
```

Debouncing:

```
static void btn_debouncing(uint8_t currEdge, struct Switch_Button *swBtn)
{
    if(currEdge == RISING)
    {
        if(swBtn->prevLvl == FALLING)
        {
            swBtn->rT = HAL_GetTick();
            swBtn->prevLvl = RISING;
        }
        else
        {
            swBtn->rT = 0;
            swBtn->fT = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(swBtn->prevLvl == RISING)
        {
            swBtn->prevLvl = FALLING;
            swBtn->fT = HAL_GetTick();
            if((swBtn->fT > swBtn->rT) && ((swBtn->fT - swBtn->rT) >= PUSH_BUTTON_TIMEOUT_MIN))
            {
                steeringModeSwBtnFlag = 1;
            }
        }
        swBtn->rT = 0;
        swBtn->fT = 0;
    }
}
```

[Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK6pE.jpg)

Comment: What are `SM_BTN0_Pin` etc defined as?

Comment: The first parameter to `btn_debouncing()` appears to be `currEdge` which gets compared with `RISING`. However, all three calls to `btn_debouncing()` pass a `SM_BTNX_Pin` as the first parameter.

Comment: Is this correct: `btn_debouncing(BTN_5, &swBtn[4]);` ? The other two similar lines use the same array index as the button number. This one doesn't.

Comment: The debouncing works well filtering out those "ghost" interrupts.  But why those interrupts were triggered when I only pressed 1 button bugs me a lot.

Comment: I don't know, it still feels like you've not shown enough code. One suggestion: ditch the `steeringModeSwBtnFlag` global variable, and have `btn_debouncing()` return a `bool` to say if there is a button press.

Comment: How do you know you are getting interrupts on the wrong pin? Do you have a breakpoint on both the lines `btn_debouncing(BTN_1, &swBtn[1]);` and `btn_debouncing(BTN_5, &swBtn[5]);` and that when you press button 5 you hit your breakpoint at line `btn_debouncing(BTN_1, &swBtn[1]);` first? If that is the case another thing to check is the disassembly for your `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback()` function. It is possible that the compiler has used a sequence of "If-Then" instructions, and your breakpoint may trigger even though the instruction does not get executed.

Comment: @tinman Yest, that is the case. I also just put one breakpoint ONLY on line 'btn_debouncing(BTN_1, &swBtn[1]);', and it stopped there once I pressed button 5. The button 1 signal was dead flat too.

Comment: This issue has been resolved by increasing the GPIO input register value from 47 to 1K Ohm.